# How to sort an object array with custom order?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object array like this:

```
[
    {keyword: 'E', value: '5'},
    {keyword: 'C', value: '3'},
    {keyword: 'B', value: '2'},
    {keyword: 'D', value: '4'},
    {keyword: 'A', value: '1'},
    {keyword: 'F', value: '6'},
    ...
]
```

I receive this array from other places and I have no control over the source, also the order that it comes can be completely random.

Now I want to sort the array with ascending order on keyword, **with the exception of swapping 2 objects.** I know the keyword of the object that I want to swap, let say C, and D in the above array. So the final result I want it to be like this:

```
[
    {keyword: 'A', value: '1'},
    {keyword: 'B', value: '2'},
    {keyword: 'D', value: '4'},
    {keyword: 'C', value: '3'},
    {keyword: 'E', value: '5'},
    {keyword: 'F', value: '6'},
    ...
]
```

I have to following code, but I don't know where to put the rest of the code. Please help!

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b){
     return a.keyword.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.keyword.toLowerCase());
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var myArray = [
  {keyword: 'E', value: '5'},
  {keyword: 'C', value: '3'},
  {keyword: 'B', value: '2'},
  {keyword: 'D', value: '4'},
  {keyword: 'A', value: '1'},
  {keyword: 'F', value: '6'}
];

var specialKeywords = [ 'C', 'D' ];

myArray.sort(function(a, b){
  //if the two being compared are 'C' and 'D', treat them special
  if (specialKeywords.indexOf(a.keyword) +1
  && specialKeywords.indexOf(b.keyword) +1) {
    //if a is 'C', it needs to be greater than 'D'
    if (a.keyword = 'C') return 1;
    else return -1;
  } else {
    //one of the elements is not 'C' or 'D', process normally.
    return a.keyword.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.keyword.toLowerCase());
  }
});

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: Works as expected! I like this one to put all the logic inside sort function. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [
    {keyword: 'E', value: '5'},
    {keyword: 'C', value: '3'},
    {keyword: 'B', value: '2'},
    {keyword: 'D', value: '4'},
    {keyword: 'A', value: '1'},
    {keyword: 'F', value: '6'},
]

var swapData =['C','D'];

data = data.sort((a,b)=> a.keyword < b.keyword?-1:1);

var [first,second] = [data.findIndex((val)=>val.keyword == swapData[0]),data.findIndex((val)=>val.keyword == swapData[1])];

var temp = data[first];
data[first] = data[second];
data[second]  = temp;

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where currying is being used to first sort the array and then swap two objects by providing two `keywords` if both of them exist in the sorted array.

```js
const a = [
    {keyword: 'E', value: '5'},
    {keyword: 'C', value: '3'},
    {keyword: 'B', value: '2'},
    {keyword: 'D', value: '4'},
    {keyword: 'A', value: '1'},
    {keyword: 'F', value: '6'},
]


//Using currying where the function is broken down into a series of functions
const sortSwap = (arrayToSort) => {
  //first sort it
  const sortedArray = arrayToSort.sort((a,b) => a.keyword.toLowerCase() > b.keyword.toLowerCase());
  return (swap1, swap2) => {
    //now swap it
    const item1 = sortedArray.findIndex(elem => elem.keyword === swap1);
    const item2 = sortedArray.findIndex(elem => elem.keyword === swap2);
    //if actually both keywords are existing in the array, proceed to swap
    if (item1 >= 0 && item2 >= 0) {
    const temp = sortedArray[item1];
    sortedArray[item1] = sortedArray[item2];
    sortedArray[item2] = temp;
    }
    return sortedArray;
  }
}


//call the function by using currying 
console.log(sortSwap(a)('A', 'C'));
```